# how to implement simple object container in C++

Tags: c++

I want to implement some object container like java bean does,for example:
I have several objects like pig,apple,dog....which may be constructed and used in my framewrok.

```
class pig:public object{
     public:
        pig(double weight);
};
class apple:public object{
     public:
        apple(int qty);
};
class dog:public object{
     public:
        dog(int qty);
};
#define kPIG 1
#define kApple 2
#define kDog  3
...
object *o1 = factory::create(kPig,100.0);
object *o2 = factory::create(kApple,2);
object *o3 = factory::create(kDog,3);
...

for those factory::creates:
1. return same type:pointer of base
2. first arg indicates the object type and followed by variable args accordingly.
```

of course I could using a factory pattern or simply 'switch-case' to create it. the key point is when the framework is published and other user adds a new object to expand the scope in binary, the framework should has ablity to recognize the new object like kPear(100) and constuct it corectly.

```
class pear:public object{
   public:
      pear(int,double,string);
}
const kPear = factory::register(pear);

object *pear =  factory::create(kPear,200,10.0,"good");
```

how can i implemente this gracefully. any sugguest or examples will be appreciated.
c++ template  will be ok.

Comment: Passing variable args will be very tricky for novice programmer as it has to be packed and then processed at runtime.

Comment: I have so many questions for you... that I don't know from where to start, so I am going to give you just an advise, add the virtual destructor to all your classes and don't pass around raw pointers (use the most suitable smart pointer).

Comment: But in general trying to bring different language solutions as it is does not work well. For example unlike java in C++ objects do not inherit single ancestor. So it is quite possible you have XY problem.

Comment: *the framework should has ability to recognize the new object like kPear(100) and constuct it corectly.* -- That would require that the new object give information to the factory on how to create itself.  All of those parameters you're passing may not be able to do that job, as a new object may have a customized or specialized way in how to create the object.  That should give you a hint that objects need an object creator that goes along with it, and then the factory uses the object creator.

Comment: emmm.thanks for replies. I think Slava get my point. actually I want to build a flexible framewokr in c++, which can manager build in objects and user objects(locacted in so/dll ,has object as father).

Comment: nebula implement java-like reflection using type_id and c++ template.it may work  on linux,but on windows/vs, export template class in dll should be a trouble thing. 
---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your class are derived from `object`. The things you can do, is to create a template function that return an pointer to an object like:

```cpp
template<class T, class... Args>
std::shared_ptr<object> create(Args&&...) {
    return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args(args)...);
}
```

Then just call it like:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<dog> my_dog = create<dog>(1);
```

Comment: thanks you.  I am studying Nebula(https://github.com/Bwar/Nebula) which has a good practice for my question

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all. I myself get a solution like below to solve this question. the only concern is arguments to callee can not be checked.this make c++ like script lang.

```
#define _xcall _cdecl
int _xcall create(int a,int b){
   return a+b;
}

class foo{
public:
  static int _xcall create(int a,int b,char*c){
     return a+b;
  }
};

using VoidFptr =void(*)();
std::unordered_map<string name,voidFptr> _creators={
{"raw",(VoidFptr)create},
{"foo",(VoidFptr)&foo:create}
};

template<typename...Arg>
int call_creator(const string &name,Arg&&...args)
{
using proto=int(*)(Arg...);
proto f=(proto)_funcs[name]
if(!f) throw;
return f(std::forward<Arg>(arg)...);
}
```